# Box-sizing border box not working, height still includes padding

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I've used box-sizing border-box with all the necessary browser prefixes and they have worked a million times. However in this example it simply doesn't work
http://eg-dev.myshopify.com/
Inspect the top left social icons. Specifically this block:

```
<div class="social-media">
    ...
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#toolbar .social-media {
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 17px;
}
```

And wildcard element box-sizing:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However div.social-media is showing up as 7px height + 5px + 5px padding. Any ideas? I checked HTML markup and it's errorfree.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand, that's what is supposed to happen. Isn't the height 17px?

Comment: It seems to work exactly as coded. It's 17px including padding.

Comment: Yikes I completely got it turned upside down, sorry my head's not right.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly how border-box works. Padding and borders do not effect the width or height of your DIV. All borders and padding are applied inside the box rather than outside